# How can I Implement a grappling hook mechanic?

Tags: game-physics, game-development, godot

I used a Raycast2D to get distance between the sprite and colliding object but can't seem to move to the desired location.

I am trying to make a grappling hook mechanic where player can throw a hook and will move to that location..
but I have no idea how to implement it with Kinmeatic2d node
I took out the distance between the sprite and collided object but cannot move to the desired location,any help would be nice...

here is my incomplete hook code:

PlayerMovement.gd:

```
func hook():
    $RayCast2D.global_position=$Sprite.global_position
    $RayCast2D.look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        var obj=$RayCast2D.get_collider()
        var disSprite=$RayCast2D.get_collision_point().distance_to($Sprite.global_position)
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("grapple"):
            print(disSprite)
            print($Sprite.global_position)
```

Scene tree:

```
Player
├ PlayerMovement
│ ├ Sprite
│ ├ CollisionShape2D
│ ├ CoyoteTimer
│ ├ Camera2D
│ ├ RayCast2D
└ TileMap
```

Comment: Can you please add syntax highlighting to your code blocks? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do so.

Comment: I have added the screenshot if it helps

Comment: This is the second time today someone has taken my request to add syntax highlighting by using the builtin formatting markup capabilities and replaced their texual code with a screenshot. Please don't. Please read the resource I linked you to to learn how to add syntax highlighting to the code blocks in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to move. However, I can see an issue in the code you posted. Since you modified the `RayCast2D` from code here:

```
    $RayCast2D.global_position=$Sprite.global_position
    $RayCast2D.look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
```

Thus the result you get here…

```
    if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        var obj=$RayCast2D.get_collider()
```

…is stale. Call `force_raycast_update` to force it to update:

```
    $RayCast2D.global_position=$Sprite.global_position
    $RayCast2D.look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    $RayCast2D.force_raycast_update()
    if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        var obj=$RayCast2D.get_collider()
        # …
```

---

Ok, you say you want to move the player over to that position *slowly*. That is not happening in the `hook` function. Instead, have a couple variables:

```
var on_hook := false
var hook_position:Vector2
```

Well, perhaps three:

```
var hook_speed := 100.0 # or something, tweak as you wish
```

Which you will set on the `hook` function:

```
    $RayCast2D.global_position=$Sprite.global_position
    $RayCast2D.look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    $RayCast2D.force_raycast_update()
    if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        var obj=$RayCast2D.get_collider()
        on_hook = true
        hook_position = $RayCast2D.get_collision_point()
```

And then in your `_physics_process` you can check:

```
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    if on_hook:
        var direction = global_position.direction_to(hook_position)
        move_and_slide(direction * hook_speed)
    else:
        # regular motion code
```

And if the hook got something, the player moves towards the position it got…

Ah, I suppose it releases when it reaches? We can do that:

```
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    if on_hook:
        var direction = global_position.direction_to(hook_position)
        move_and_slide(direction * hook_speed)

        var distance := global_position.distance_to(hook_position)
        if distance < hook_speed * delta:
            # reached the destination
            on_hook = false
    else:
        # regular motion code
```

We are not checking if the distance is zero because it won't reach zero due to floating point errors. Instead we are checking if the distance is less than what it would advance in one frame.

Comment: Thanks fyi..
I wanted the player(sprite) to move to the hooked position .
I don't need the the grappling hook to swing, just stick to a surface and slowly carry the player over to its position.

I am somewhat new to Gdscript and godot in general, so i would really appreciate the help.

Comment: @noobfatherofcoders You want to move the sprite only?

Comment: yes along with the collision body